# SpriteKit Devices

Tags: swift, spritekit

Можно ли прописать код отдельно для разных девайсов? Например у меня везде размер объекта один, а на 4s хочу чтобы был другой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно при помощи

```
struct utsname systemInfo;
uname(&systemInfo);
NSString *machineName = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

либо через размер экрана

```
if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 480) { //тут ваш код }
```

Comment: А как при помощи размера экрана?

        if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 480) || ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 480)
        {
}

Comment: добавил в ответ. Если размер экрана 480, значит вы скорее всего на iPhone4 - делайте свой кастом хэндлинг